# counting pulses from encoder on interrupt 0 pin every 50 ms

Tags: c++, interrupt, timers, rotary-encoder

I want to calculate the number of pulses coming from motor1 encoder pin2 (Int0) as input , and motor 2 encoder pin3 (Int1), I am working now for the first motor (just for the first motor ) so I set timer 2 to count 50 ms then throw flag in this moment I have to send the number of pulses to my screen, but not succeeded cause i see   on my screen zeros and ascii caracters but not the  number of pulses.:this my code .

```
 volatile int  pulses = 0;

 int flag=0;
 int setbit = 0;
 int encoder_in = 2;
 void count() {

       pulses++;
     }

  void setup()
   {



 Serial.begin(115200);
 pinMode(encoder_in, INPUT);
digitalWrite(2, HIGH); //Enable pullup

// initialize timer2
 noInterrupts();           // disable all interrupts

TCCR2A = 0x00;
 TCCR2B = 0x07;  
TCNT2 = 0x64;
//EIMSK = 0x03;     // Enable external interrupt INT0
//EICRA = 0x0f;    // Trigger INT0 on falling edge 

 TIMSK2 |= 0x01;  // enable timer compare interrupt
interrupts();             // enable all interrupts
attachInterrupt(0,count,RISING);

 }
  ISR(TIMER2_OVF_vect)        
{
TCNT2 = 0x64;            // preload timer
 setbit=setbit+1;
  if(setbit==5)
  {
  flag=1;
 setbit=0;

   }
}

 //ISR(EXT_INT0_vect)
 //{ pulses++; }



 void loop()
{

 if (flag==1)
 {

   Serial.println(pulses);
    pulses=0; 


  }
  }
```

Comment: a) what is your question?, and b) what does "not succeed" mean?  Does the  print statement not work?  Is the count it shows inaccurate?  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i see on my screen zeros and ascii caracters not number of pulses.

Comment: Separate out the problem.  Just try to print ANY integer, and don't worry about counting the pulses until you have this right.  Note that at first glance, your issue seems to have NOTHING to do with what you said it was in the title.

Comment: Try changing `volatile int  pulses = 0;` to `volatile int  pulses = 1;` and see if you now get `1`s printed. Also which ascii characters do you see? Can you give us a sample output.

Comment: Do you have anything attached to pins 0 or 1 of the Arduino?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your technique looks convoluted to me. How about this?

```C++
volatile bool counting;
volatile unsigned long events;

unsigned long startTime;
const unsigned long INTERVAL = 50;  // ms

void eventISR ()
  {
  if (counting)
    events++;    
  }  // end of eventISR

void setup ()
  {
  Serial.begin (115200);
  Serial.println ();
  pinMode (2, INPUT_PULLUP);
  attachInterrupt (0, eventISR, RISING);
  }  // end of setup

void showResults ()
  {
  Serial.print ("I counted ");
  Serial.println (events);
  }  // end of showResults

void loop ()
  {
  if (counting)
    {
    // is time up?
    if (millis () - startTime < INTERVAL)
      return;  
    counting = false;
    showResults ();
    }  // end of if

  noInterrupts ();
  events = 0;
  startTime = millis ();
  EIFR = bit (INTF0);  // clear flag for interrupt 0
  counting = true;
  interrupts ();
  }  // end of loop
```

---

#### Explanation

Using a timer to detect when 50 ms is up isn't particularly helpful in this case. You can't do printing inside an ISR, so you would have to set a flag that can be checked in the main loop.

If you are going to check a flag anyway, you may as well just check if the time is up, as my code does.

Inside the ISR, I stop adding to `events` if the flag `counting` is false. This is to stop `events` being changed at the exact moment it is being printed.

Comment: that's work thank you Mr Nick, but I tried to calculate for both Motor but it not Works , I Tried  many Times but not works, may you  can see my code:

Comment: whats the "Return" instruction in loop() exactly do. 
I am working to calculate for the second Motor but it not work.

Comment: `may you can see my code` - amend your question to add this new code so I can see it.

Comment: `whats the "Return" instruction in loop() exactly do` - it returns from the `loop()` function, which then gets called again.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Baud Rate in Serial Monitor. If baud rate is not correct i.e. 9600 bps then it will show garbage.

Remove the Timer and Wire Libs

add this code in void setup()

```
attachInterrupt(0,void_counter,RISING);
```

the above is for the the external interrupt input.

and attach your sensor/incoming pulse wire on Pin 2 on arduino.

make a new function like this

```
void_counter(){ 
pulses++;
}
```

Comment: I agree with this. But it is more appropriated as a comment.

Comment: New to stack exchange.

Comment: Also he already enabled the Interrupt, but by registers

Comment: i did this change before and now too i did what you told me, but  I still see characters like {0¤0, A,P,. . }

Comment: I see the pulses on oscilloscope but still I cant see the number of pulses on my monitr